# vlc-android: Audio filter audio normalization (normvol) is not working

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

When trying to normalize the audio(mov file) using vlc-android, it seems to not work. Below is the command which was added to options:|

options.add("--audio-filter=normvol") options.add("--norm-buff-size=20") options.add("--norm-max-level=4")

After using the same we were not able to notice any difference. Some other filters also does not seem to work.

Git link: https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android
Usage link: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/

Let us know in case we are missing something here. The above mentioned commands seems to work in the linux environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated